# File Service Architecture & Cost Analysis

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, network-programming, cloud, storage

**Context**

I am developping a webapp that

1. Takes an URL from the user
2. Downloads and stores the associated file onto my server
3. The user can fetch the file from my server at any time before the file is eventually expired and removed

I am planning to deploy this application on the AWS. More specifically, using EC2 and S3.

**Challenge**

I am trying to come up with a design that is both cost-effective and performant to offer this service.

**Analysis**

The following assumptions are used:

- the downloaded file will be available to only one user, the one who provided the URL and initiated the download
- the user will only fetch the file once from the server
- the file will only stay on the server for at maximum 24 hours before getting removed
- the file sizes are in the 100MB - 5GB range

Consider the following application flow:

1. Internet → EC2: Download the file onto local storage
2. EC2 → S3: Upload the downloaded file onto S3, deletes the local copy on EC2
3. EC2 → User: Provide the user with a direct URL to fetch from S3
4. S3 → user: The user fetches the file from S3
5. S3: file is removed after 24 hours.

In terms of network performance, step 1 and 2 will be the bottlenecks as EC2 has limited downloading and uploading bandwidth. Step 4 should not be a problem since S3 is taking care of the bandwidth for transferring file to the end user.

In terms of costs, fixed costs are the EC2 instances, and the main variable cost is step 4, where AWS charges 0.09$/GB in data transfer. Since the files are removed after 24 hours, the storage fee is comparatively tiny.

**Question**

1. Have I correctly identified the performance bottlenecks in this application flow?
2. Is my cost analysis correct?
3. Is this the optimal flow in terms of costs? Is there any way to further reduce the cost?
4. Since step 1 and step 2 (downloading from Internet and uploading to S3) will be very bandwidth-consuming when simultaneously downloading multiple large files, will it significantly affect the responsiveness of my server to serve regular API requests? Should I use a dedicated EC2 instance just for handling API calls from the clients, and another dedicated EC2 instance just for downloading and uploading? This will slightly further complicate the design, as I will have to manage the communication between the 2 instances as well.

Comment: One potential death point is if a bunch of users do this at once and fill up your EC2 local storage quickly enough, causing a bunch of errors as the server tries to expand the files while appending to them. Is there a way to immediately send on received web data to S3 using a small fixed RAM buffer instead of storing the whole file?

Comment: @Olathe Thanks for your input! I have thought about this situation, it could be avoided by setting up a queue for downloading tasks and setting a limit on how many downloads are allowed simultaneously and give the EC2 local storage a generous amount of buffering space. Other download tasks can start only after the some files are uploaded to S3 and spaces freed.

Comment: What load and performance requirements do you have? How many users do you expect to be uploading/downloading at once? Why do you assume the user will only download the file once? Can you provide more context on what this will be used for?

Comment: I wouldnt even have the file touch EC2 storage or worry about a RAM buffer.  Just use the webapp on EC2 as a proxy to stream directly to S3.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use more AWS Services? Are you aware of AWS Lambda? https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/details/ It can perform actions in response to actions, e.g. it could delete a file from S3 shortly after it is downloaded. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html
This alleviates the need to track downloads and delete them, once you get past the learning curve of AWS Lambda. It can also handle other processing, so you only have to upload to S3 from EC2.

Regarding cost, S3 has different quality levels, and the "reduced redundancy" might be sufficient for your needs, saving a little money.

Comment: Great suggestions on AWS Lambda! I have come across the service, but I could not find any information on how much bandwidth would it give me (which would ultimately determine how fast a download would finish) and how does it handle long-running tasks. From What I read, seems like AWS lambda functions need to return within 300 seconds. But what if the file downloading process takes longer than 300 seconds? I will look more into this. Thank you again for the suggestions. I will wait for a few more hours and if there are no other replies, the bounty is yours :)

Answer (score 1):

How about allowing the client to upload files directly to S3?

Your application would generate a pre-signed url, so that you can control which users can upload files, but after that the client interacts directly with S3. This would remove the costly "download then upload" process in steps 1 & 2.

See this document http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The whole point of the service is to download a resource that's hosted on the internet for the user, so letting the client to upload files does not apply in this case.

Comment: Oh ok, I probably I misunderstood who would be uploading the files in the first place. I was thinking that you could avoid this problem "In terms of network performance, step 1 and 2 will be the bottlenecks as EC2 has limited downloading and uploading bandwidth." by directly uploading to S3 from "the internet" described in step 1. You could use lambda to generate the token used to upload directly to S3.